Generating -3 V Vbb for an ailing Amiga Alice chip (NMOS)
Background: I have an Amiga 1200 computer (ca. 1992) with a problem that seems to be caused by a bad Vbb voltage associated with the Alice chip (address generator, DMA controller, blitter, etc.). As I understand it, this back-bias voltage is generated within the chip for its 5 V HMOS (NMOS) logic, and should normally be around -3 V. However, on this machine, it starts around -1 V at cold boot and collapses to -0.1 V after about half a minute of operation (once the chip reaches ~45°C). At this point, the CCKQ clock signal generated by Alice collapses to about 2 Vp-p and the system stops working properly. However, supplying -3 V externally from a lab power supply seems to fix the problem entirely, and draws negligible current (0.000 A shown on the display). Interestingly, doing so also causes Alice to run a few degrees cooler and the system draws a little less power (a few tens of mA on the +5 V).
Alice's Vbb is (normally) generated internally and made available on an external pin to allow stabilisation with a capacitor. With reference to the schematic, Vbb decoupling for Alice (U2, pin 55) is shown on Sheet 6; the problematic clock signal is CCKQ (colour clock, quadrature), which appears on Sheet 2.
I should mention that during testing I isolated Alice's CCKQ pin by desoldering series resistors E129R and E128R, in case the signal was being loaded down by bad passives or other devices that receive the clock signal. This made no difference: the CCKQ signal still dropped to 2 Vp-p and Vbb dropped to -0.1 V at the same time.
My question then is how to fix this permanently by providing the -3 V on the board. The system has a -12 V power rail for analog audio and RS-232 circuits, so a voltage divider might be an option, though the voltage varies depending on the power supply (I've seen more like -15 V). I would also prefer to be able to run the system entirely from +5 V for testing.
I wondered if a charge pump (perhaps regulated) might be a reasonable option, though I'm not familiar with these in terms of design and part selection. Since it's a one-off fix, something hobbyist-friendly would be preferable.
I've heard of people using the MAX232 as a convenient way to generate negative voltages, too, though I'm not sure how easily it could be made to generate -3 V (though from my testing it seems anything from about -1.5 V to -3 V would work).

What current did you measure from your -3 V supply when you used the bench supply and everything was working nicely? Also, is there any way you can provide a link to a schematic of this system? (Perhaps from bitsavers?)

If you are really unlucky, the -3 V generation is working properly but the consumption is too high. IC's don't tend to fail soft like that though. Is there anything else fed with -3 V? Is anything getting hotter than normal? Can you hook it up to an external current limited lab power supply, feed it -3 V and see if it makes any difference?

I've amended my question to be more specific about the current draw on the -3 V feed: the power supply shows no measurable current.

I do have a working A1200 (slightly different revision) and the Alice chip runs about 10 K cooler on the healthy board. However, with the -3 V fed to Vbb, the faulty Alice runs cooler (closer to normal). I did also find that placing a decent heat sink on the chip would keep things running for longer (without the external -3 V supply).

According to the schematics, that particular -3 V Vbb node is generated and used solely by the Alice chip. I also desoldered and uprated the C2X bypass cap in case it was faulty, with no improvement.

@screwtop If the current draw is so insignificant that you can't measure it, then a resistor divider from your -12 V supply may work. So perhaps this test might be the next step. (The other alternative is to debug the existing supply. But without a schematic for it, I can't make any suggestions.) What can you say about the worst-case current requirement given that you cannot measure the current from your bench supply? What's its limitations? Do you feel able to arrange a resistor divider from the -12 V supply and also disconnect from the existing supply? It's a hack. But worth a try.

I could put a DMM in series with the bench supply to get a better idea, but I'd be confident that it's <10 mA. I think the internal details of the chips are not available, and I get the impression that Alice was quite a complex ASIC for the time, and they clearly had issues with clock signal quality in general (evidenced by buffers, a bodge wire, and a pull-up resistor on production boards). Thanks for the suggestions!

Another reason I was pondering a charge pump was that there's +5 V conveniently available at the chip, whereas hooking up to -12 V would involve some longer wiring. But I can certainly give it a try.

I should clarify: the -3 V is generated (somehow!) within the Alice chip itself, and earlier revisions did not even provide a Vbb pin, so it was completely internal and inaccessible. Later revisions added the Vbb pin apparently to allow external stabilisation with a larger capacitor. I should count myself lucky, as without it there might be no hope of fixing this!

@screwtop You can readily get -3 V, 10 mA compliance, from this. Actually, that might produce closer to -4 V. But if you use 1N4148's instead of the BAT54's then it probably will be close to -3 V.

The folks on retrocomputing might have some insight into an issue like this.
